# Error if I try to open new View on appcelerator

Tags: view, appcelerator

I'm building a simple app with appcelerator.
So I have the index view that when the application is started, I want that this index view open Login view.

So I have this:

**login.xml**

```
<Alloy>
    <View class="container">
        <View class="images"></View>
        <Label id="loginLable"
            class="loginLable">Accedi</Label>
        <TextField class="textLogin"></TextField>

    </View>
</Alloy>
```

**login.js**

```
// Arguments passed into this controller can be accessed via the `$.args` object directly or:
var args = $.args;

function loginEventListener(e){
    Ti.API.info("You clicked the button");
};
```

**index.js**

```
var login = Alloy.createController("login",args).getView();
login.open();
```

If I try to start this application, I have this error:

```
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [19654,21610] ----- Titanium Javascript Runtime Error -----
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [0,21610] - In alloy/controllers/index.js:35,11
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [2,21612] - Message: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<View> has no method 'open'
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [1,21613] - Source:     login.open();
[ERROR] :  V8Exception: Exception occurred at alloy/controllers/index.js:35: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<View> has no method 'open'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot "open" a view. It needs a container. You can either add it to an already opened window, or you need to make the controller a window. `open()` doesn't exist for the view.

```
<Alloy>
    <Window>
    <View class="container">
        <View class="images"></View>
        <Label id="loginLable"
            class="loginLable">Accedi</Label>
        <TextField class="textLogin"></TextField>

    </View>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

Then, to open it you can do the same as you did already